# How to create a trigger for insert and update data

Tags: sql-server, ssis, triggers

How to create a trigger for insert and update that will automatically transfer data from one (source)table to another (destionation)table (tables in different databases)? 
Trigger needs to transfer data after each change in the source table. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: And what to do on delete? And how you will store changes? If you need exact copy it is better to use a view. Too broad for now, please, elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
USE DB1;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.table1__AIU
    ON dbo.table1
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @operation char(1) = -- [I]nsert, [U]pdate, u[N]known
        CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) THEN 
                CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted) THEN 'U' ELSE 'I' END 
            ELSE 'N' 
        END;

    IF @operation = 'N'
        RETURN;

    IF @operation = 'I'
        INSERT INTO DB2.dbo.Table2(id, b)
            SELECT inserted.id, inserted.b
            FROM inserted;
    ELSE
        UPDATE t2 
            SET b = inserted.b
            FROM DB2.dbo.Table2 t2
            INNER JOIN inserted i ON t2.id = inserted.id;
END;
GO
```

Comment: The virtual tables `inserted` and `deleted` can contain multiple rows for batch inserts/updates/deletes. What you wrote is incorrect because you are assuming those tables only contain one row. So this is going to be incorrect for batch inserts/updates/deletes. Also the insert and update statements at the end of the trigger are incorrect. You can't write them that way. The insert statement can't just refer to inserted.XXX within a VALUES clause, the update statement can't refer to inserted.XXX without having the inserted table in a FROM clause.

Comment: @TT, yes, you are right, it's a hurry( I changed answer, thank you